# Strongloop tutorial running error

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am going through the Strongloop documentation. In the tutorial [Add a client app](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Add+a+client+app) I followed the steps that are given. I am able to run the app with `slc run` without error. But when checked in the browser there is error that `angular is not defined` in `app.js`.

In case if I include angular.js from google i.e. just uncomment in app.js

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>`

There is error on browser:

`Error: [$injector:modulerr] .....`

So what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The example is outdated, we have a new tutorial here: `https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-getting-started`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Still the same issue. I'll wait for documentation and the example app to be in sync.